# Cannot get HTTPD 2.4 to start when using the Require IP command for access control

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, cidr

This was intended to be a comment on a similar question but since Stack is so restrictive about comments I'm reposting it as they want it:

: Here's the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require)

Here's the config file: 
`Options Indexes FollowSymLinks AllowOverride None Require ip $CIDR ~`

The error still is: May 24 20:54:54 ip-172-16-5-34.us-west-1.compute.internal httpd[23044]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd.conf: May 24 20:54:54 ip-172-16-5-34.us-west-1.compute.internal httpd[23044]: Invalid command 'Require', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

What am I missing?

It looks like the RequireAny or RequireAll commands may help but they don't.

For your reference the information provided here did not suffice:
[How do I require an IP range instead of 1 IP?](https://serverfault.com/questions/682490/how-do-i-require-an-ip-range-instead-of-1-ip/778846?noredirect=1#comment983453_778846)

Answer (score 2):

`Require ip $CIDR ~` is not proper in the [`Options` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#options). The documentation is very clear about what may be in an `Options` directive.

[`Require` is its own directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require), which can be in a Container, but certainly not within an `Options` directive.

When you get past that, your next problem will probably be the `Require ip $CIDR ~`. Where are you getting this `$CIDR ~` bit? You need to follow proper specification for [access control by host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html#host) and specification of [`Require ip` directives](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html#requiredirectives).

If in fact, you actually have `Require ip $CIDR ~` on its own config line, as opposed to what you put in the question, then refer to the last part of this answer now (i.e. use proper host/ip specification with the `Require ip`) and also see the following notes.

NOTE: You must have `mod_authz_core` loaded to use the `Require` (and related) directives.

NOTE ALSO: You should be running `apachectl -t` to check config changes BEFORE trying to restart Apache, rather than finding these problems by crashing Apache.